# SimpleCursorAdapter showing all rows even when specifying cursor in constructor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, simplecursoradapter

```
Cursor cursor = coursesOpenHelper.getCoursesByTerm(db, TERM);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor,
            new String[]
            {
                    "course",
            },
            new int[]
            {
                    android.R.id.text1,
            },
            0);

    // test the cursor to see that it has the correct number of records
    int x = cursor.getCount();
    Toast.makeText(this, x+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the getCoursesByTerm method:

```
public Cursor getCoursesByTerm(final SQLiteDatabase db, int term){
    final Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.query(COURSE_TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            "term = "+term,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(context.getContentResolver(), CourseContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
    return (cursor);
}
```

I know that this method is returning the correct Cursor with the correct number of rows, but the ListView is showing all of the rows. Let me know if you need to see any of my other code. Thanks!

EDIT: I've discovered my problem... this is a subclass of all my TermActivity classes. Commenting out the one line of code solves my problem, but I'm sure this is a very incorrect way of doing it.

```
private class CourseLoaderCallbacks implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(final int    id,
                                         final Bundle args)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
        final Uri uri;
        final CursorLoader loader;

        uri    = CourseContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
        loader = new CursorLoader(Term1Activity.this, uri, null, null, null, null);

        return (loader);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(final Loader<Cursor> loader,
                               final Cursor         data)
    {
        //adapter.swapCursor(data); // was swapping cursor for null, resulting in all courses showing
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(final Loader<Cursor> loader)
    {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: so `db.query` returns, lets say 4 rows, but your `SimpleCursorAdapter` shows all the rows from your `COURSE_TABLE_NAME`?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: the data is taken from your Cursor, if it holds 4 rows your adapter cannot show more... where would it get from?

Comment: The database 'course' table has 29 total rows, I am trying to filter each ListView to only show courses from one term. So Term 1 should be 7, Term 2 is 7, Term 3 is 7, and Term 4 is 8. In my Toast I print the number of rows in the cursor that is being grabbed and it is correct, however the ListView continues to show all the rows in the database table. I don't really understand your question.

Comment: The SimpleCursorAdapter behaves as if I passed null for the Cursor parameter but I didn't.

Comment: if you are not sure about your cursor content use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` method and use `Log.d` for debugging purposes, not `Toast`

Comment: Using Toast isn't causing my problem.

Comment: again, for debugging use `Log.d`, not `Toast`

Comment: I'm getting the same result, a Cursor with 7 entries. The ListView shows 29...

Comment: so after `adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor, ...` call `Log.d` and log two integers: `cursor.getCount` and `adapter.getCount`, if `adapter.getCount` shows 7 and you see 29 items so you have to set the adapter in different place...

Comment: Adapter count and cursor count are both 7 :/ but the ListView shows more

Comment: how come? `adapter.getCount` tels the `ListView` how many items to show, check the other places where you call `setAdapter`

Comment: I only call listView.setAdapter once, after defining the adapter with the cursor.

Comment: ok so create a custom `SCA` and override `bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)` and log the cursor inside

Comment: I don't wish to extend SCA. Thanks for trying.

Comment: just for testing, you will see what cursor you are using

Comment: I've debugged my app and discovered that it is the onLoadFinished method of my class that implements LoaderCallBacks<Cursor> that swaps the cursor to null.

Comment: if it swaps cursor to null cursor so how you can see any data from a null cursor? for testing try this: http://pastebin.com/SuM8ecrr, you will see what cursor is used by your `SCA`

Comment: When null is passed in place of a cursor, the adapter simply uses all of the rows in the table.

Comment: what rows if you are passing a null Cursor? so where does it get data from? did you try that custom adapter i posted?

Comment: I debugged my program and I know what was causing the issue. I added an edit above.

Comment: so if you are using a custom `ContentProvider` why are you using things like `coursesOpenHelper.getCoursesByTerm` ?